# why fail to request url in ajax when

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is my ajax code

```
function buatajax(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}
function checkout() {
    var url = "index3.php";
    url = url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    ajaxku = buatajax();
    ajaxku.onreadystatechange=checkoutisi;
    ajaxku.open("GET",url,true);
    ajaxku.send(null);
}
function checkoutisi() {
    if(ajaxku.readyState == 4){
        data = ajaxku.responseText;
        document.getElementById('isiecon').innerHTML = data;
        alert(data);
    }
}
```

when i alert data as it's shown, it said that the requested url not found.
I'm using localhost server for now, instead of using jquery ajax, how to use ajax in my way? because i dont really understand the jquery ajax way.

Comment: Is `index3.php` in the same folder as the HTML file running the Javascript?

Comment: The error in the Javascript console should show you the full URL that it's trying to use.

Comment: Check your Network tab to see if the request is going where you want it to go.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ajaxku` variable is undefined inside `checkoutisi` function. Can u check that?

Comment: yes index3.php is the same folder @Barmar

Comment: what do you mean by network tab? @CertainPerformance

Comment: but the other ajax that is using this code is running idk why @StyleSh1t

Comment: @EricAnthonyWu I mean in your browser - look at the Network tab, or your Javascript console, it should tell you more precisely what's failing